# Как объединить два DataFrame в один?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть два DataFrame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lit':['a', 'b', 'c']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'num':['1', '2', '3']})
```

Необходимо объединить DataFrame таким образом, чтобы каждой строке первого DataFrame соответствовали все строки второго DataFrame.

Ожидаемый результат:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lit':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],  
                   'num':['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно [декартово произведение множеств](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) :

```
res = df1.assign(x=1).merge(df2.assign(x=1)).drop(columns="x")
```

результат:

```
In [30]: res
Out[30]:
  lit num
0   a   1
1   a   2
2   a   3
3   b   1
4   b   2
5   b   3
6   c   1
7   c   2
8   c   3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product
res = pd.DataFrame(product(df1.values.ravel(), df2.values.ravel()))
res.columns = ['lit', 'num']
```

результат:

```
   lit  num
0   a   1
1   a   2
2   a   3
3   b   1
4   b   2
5   b   3
6   c   1
7   c   2
8   c   3
```